# Jquery .animate() delay on .mouseleave()

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {   
    if (event.pageX == 0) {
        $("#nav").animate({
            marginLeft: '0px',
        });  
    }        
});

$("#nav").mouseleave(function(event) {   
    $(this).animate({
        marginLeft: '-220px',
    });      
    alert('hi');  
});
```

Basically I have a slider coming out the left side of the webpage.The problem is on .mouseleave() it does not animate the slider back to -220px. Sometimes it does but it has some kind of delay. Its strange because the alert triggers instantly. How can I improve this?

Comment: a jsfiddle.net example would be great including your html and css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to the fact that the mouseMove event is queuing up one animation each time the mouse moves over x=0. This is causing all of those animations to run to completion before the mouseleave animation can take effect.

A simple fix for this is to add .stop() calls before running .animate(). This will stop all animations in queue so the .animate() call will take effect immediately.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {   
    if (event.pageX == 0) {
        $("#nav").stop().animate({
            marginLeft: '0px',
        });  
    }        
});

$("#nav").mouseleave(function(event) {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        marginLeft: '-220px',
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the new way: `$( selector ).on( "mouseenter mouseleave", handlerInOut );`

Here is the FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/mikea80/pmGfp/

Here is the code:

```
$('div').on( "mouseenter", function() {
     $('p').text('you are over');
});

$('div').on( "mouseleave", function() {
     $('p').text('you are out');  
});
```

Hope this helps